# What is the best practice making an email tracking system?

Tags: email, tracking

I'm about to start on an an application where one of the features needed is a way for tracking emails reading status. I've been looking around the net and some of the apps out there uses remote images for tracking.
So I was wandering what the best practice was here?

Thanks for your help.

Lars

Comment: Ick!  Thankfully for us, most email clients require us to approve of external images in emails in order to prevent *just such snooping*.

Comment: Also many of us won't follow personalized links, because spammers use them to see who clicked on what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image tracking is probably the easiest way. But if the receiver of the email views it purely as plain text and disallows image loading, there's really nothing you can do to track when it was accessed.

Comment: Most email readers routinely block image downloads as a privacy feature.  A blocked image download would prevent you from determining if an email was read.  At best such a system would underestimate.

Comment: Yes, exactly. If one couldn't be pretty sure of the tracking accuracy, it becomes essentially worthless.